# Knockout databinding to definition lists in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Internet Explorer strikes again! In IE7 and 8 knockout fails to bind to a definition list. If I use the same code as below but change it to an unordered list, magic it all works. Unfortunatley the UX team say I should use definition lists so not sure what to do here? Any thoughts?

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: geofences">
    <li class="geofenceData">
        <h3 data-bind="text: Alias, click: $root.selectGeofence"></h3>
        <div class="holder" >
                <dl class="datalist">
                    <dt>@LanguageResources.Geofence.Name.Text</dt>
                    <dd><span  data-bind="text: Alias"/></dd> 

                    <dt>@LanguageResources.Geofence.IsPrimary.Text:</dt>
                    <dd><span  data-bind="text: IsPrimary"/></dd> 
                 </dl>
         </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your `<span />` tags with `<span></span>`.